# To find the boundary of the following set

Tags: real-analysis

Given set $(- \infty, \sqrt2] \cap ℚ \subseteq ℝ$.
I know that the boundary is closure\interior, but
I always have trouble to find the closure and interior of a set like this. Can someone please explain how to find the closure and interior for this particular one?

Comment: I do not think boundary is closure minus interior.  Rather, a boundary point of $A\subseteq X$ is a point which is in the closure of $A$ and $X\setminus A$. The boundary of $A$ is the set of all of its boundary points.

Comment: @Forever what would the $X\setminus A$ be in this case? Sorry, I just really don't get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my definition of boundary in the comment above.

Let $A=(-\infty,\sqrt 2]\cap \mathbb Q$.

Boundary point of $A$ must be a limit points in $A$, therefore $\partial A\subseteq (-\infty,\sqrt 2]$ because $(-\infty,\sqrt 2]$ contains all of the limit points of $A$ ($A$ is contained in $(-\infty,\sqrt 2]$, and $(-\infty,\sqrt 2]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$).

The rationals and irrationals are dense in $(-\infty,\sqrt 2]$, so $(-\infty,\sqrt 2] \subseteq \partial A$.

Therefore $\partial A=(-\infty,\sqrt 2]$.